# VHDL Simualtion result discrepency

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim

I am trying to simulate my VHDL code. There appears to be a discrepancy as the bits q(0 down to 0) and q1(0 down to 0) have some value, but then when I assign them to new vectors, they have incorrect values (in the same cycle)[see ModelSim simulation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mldk6.jpg). Since my next state logic depends on these two bits, it's turning out to be incorrect.

Here, r and t are assigned to q(0 downto 0) and q1(0 down to 0) as shown in the code. In the example, r should take the value 1 as q[0] is one. But it comes out to be 0.

I am wondering as to what can be the cause of this issue?

```
when S0 =>  state <= S0;
        funct <= '0';       
        load_m <= '0';
        load_a <= '0';
        load_q <= '0';
        load_q1 <= '0';
        shift <= '0';
        dc <= '0';
        rst_counter <= '0';
        rst_shifter <= '0';
        done <= '0';



        --q0 <= to_bit(q(0 downto 0));
        --q11 <= to_bit(q1);

        r <= q(0 downto 0);
        t <= q1(0 downto 0);

        if ( (q(0 downto 0) = "1" and q1(0 downto 0) = "1") or (q(0 downto 0) = "0" and q1(0 downto 0) = "0")) then
        next_state <= S4;

        elsif (q(0 downto 0) = "0" and q1(0 downto 0) = "1") then
        next_state <= S2;

        elsif (q(0 downto 0) = "1" and q1(0 downto 0) = "0") then
        next_state <= S1;
        end if;
```

Comment: Your code example isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In VHDL it's generally helpful to see the declarations, structure, complete processes and all signal assignments involved. There isn't sufficient information to answer.   Is there some reason you're using array types with a length of 1 instead of it's element type?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, I am unable to tell. I recommend writing a testbench and simulating it (I use modelsim). That way you will be able to see how signals are changing, and more than likely you will figure out your problem.